# Problem with installing libraries from git.rancher.io on Rancher 2.4

Tags: git, rancher

I'm getting error messages on any catalog library install from the git.ranchar.io as

[image]

and logs in the Rancher docker:

```
2020/08/12 16:32:17 [ERROR] CatalogController helm3-library [catalog] failed with : Update failed: error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
: exit status 1
2020/08/12 16:32:17 [ERROR] CatalogController system-library [catalog] failed with : Update failed: error: pathspec 'origin/release-v2.4' did not match any file(s) known to git.
: exit status 1, [system-image-upgrade-catalog-controller] failed with : upgrade cluster c-chx55 system service alerting failed: get template cattle-global-data:system-library-rancher-monitoring failed, catalogTemplate.management.cattle.io "cattle-global-data/system-library-rancher-monitoring" not found
2020/08/12 16:32:17 [ERROR] CatalogController library [catalog] failed with : Update failed: error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any clue what is wrong with those default git repos?